# Is it possible to use deleteCascade with esqueleto?

Tags: haskell, esqueleto, haskell-persistent

I did not found any mentions of deleteCascade and deleteCascadeWhere in esqueleto... Is there an esqueleto equivalent to these functions?

Comment: Oddly enough, persistent's `deleteCascade` is re-exported via Database.Esqueleto but `deleteCascadeWhere` is not. Can you just use persistent's deleteCascade / deleteCascadeWith?

Comment: I asked the question on esqueleto's bugtracker: https://github.com/prowdsponsor/esqueleto/issues/147